# TOTP 2FA option is not appearing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 (remi repository). I've installed all of the pre-requisites that I know of:

```
yum install php-pragmarx-google2fa php-bacon-qr-code php-samyoul-u2f-php-server
```

But only U2F is showing up on phpMyAdmin Settings for two factor authentication.

As far as I can tell, database storage is configured. I had it working on a previous version of phpMyAdmin, but since the upgrade it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Try with "php-pragmarx-google2fa-qrcode"  (btw, this dependency should be pulled by phpMyAdmin, mandatory on old distribution, recommended on new distribution)

Comment: I checked and it says it's already installed.

Comment: I found this, but don't know how to apply it: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247134... For clarity, php-xml-7.4.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64  is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed an issue with the old builds.

Please try the latest build (version 5.1.0-2) which has a fix for this.